# Switching Div's on Refresh

Tags: javascript, php

I have a div at the top of the page, middle, and bottom.  When I refresh the page each time I would like the top and bottom divs to switch without affecting the middle div at all.  Thanks in advance for any answers.

[My jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jLhw9ads/1/)

**Code:**

```css
.top {
  background: lightpink;
  padding: 40px;
}

.content {
  background: white;
}

.bottom {
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  1
</div>

<div class="content">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam fuga impedit, obcaecati, commodi dolores quasi odit numquam esse aliquid, alias natus doloribus nihil eius dicta eaque, nobis veritatis! Praesentium, laboriosam.
</div>

<div class="bottom">
  2
</div>
```

Comment: You have not tried anything with JS and you are asking people to do this for you!!!

Comment: Interchange the values 1 and 2  is what you need?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using `sessionStorage` and cloning divs.

What this is doing is taking a copy of each div in the clone variables and then using a sessionStorage value to toggle between the states. If the `sessionStorage` value is 0 then it will do nothing but change the value, if it's 1 then it'll remove the divs and then add them in the new order from the cloned content.

```
var divOne = document.querySelector('.top');
var divTwo = document.querySelector('.bottom');
var divOneClone = document.querySelector('.top').outerHTML;
var divTwoClone = document.querySelector('.bottom').outerHTML;
var divContent = document.querySelector('.content');

if (sessionStorage.getItem('refreshState')) {

    if (sessionStorage.getItem('refreshState') == 1) {

    divOne.parentNode.removeChild(divOne);
    divTwo.parentNode.removeChild(divTwo);
    divContent.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', divTwoClone);
    divContent.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', divOneClone);
    sessionStorage.setItem('refreshState', 0);

  } else {

    sessionStorage.setItem('refreshState', 1);

  }

} else {
    sessionStorage.setItem('refreshState', 0);
}
```

Here's a working [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jLhw9ads/4/) example.